# Define main file without defining the parameters in the main file

Tags: python

I have two .py files, one is Setting.py and one is main.py.

In the Setting.py file I have the following code:

```
a= 2
def foo(a): 
  return a+2
```

In the main file I have this:

```
import Setting

if __name__ == '__main__':

    X = foo(a)
```

So, when I run the main file, I get the error that a is not defined. So, I dont want again to define a in the main file. Could you please help me with this? this is a minimal code of my main code. I have multiple .py files and parameters. Thanks

Comment: `from Setting import a`. Even then, it's hit and hope with your minimal example

Comment: You can either say `X = Setting.foo(Setting.a)`, or you can use `from Setting import foo, a`.

Comment: You could define `foo` as `def foo(a=a):` and then call it with `X = foo()`. That would still give you the option of redefining `a` by passing a different argument in.

Comment: Actually, _both_ are imported from `Setting`. This is a design flaw (you know that `main` doesn't mean anything in Python in terms of user-defined module/function names?). `if __name__ == '__main__'` does not relate to the filenames you've given or the function names

Answer (score 1):

You could try either
`from Setting import *` or `from Setting import foo,a`.